# How to provide custom type conversion of a PowerShell parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, type-conversion

I have a scenario where one of the parameters to my cmdlet is a tuple of a CSV file name and the name of a column header. I would like to properly import that as a tuple with type `[System.Tuple[System.IO.FileInfo,String]]`. The full code looks like this:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[ValidateScript( {
        if (-Not ($_.item1 | Test-Path) ) {
            throw "File or folder does not exist"
        }
        if (-Not ($_.item1 | Test-Path -PathType Leaf) ) {
            throw "The Path argument must be a file. Folder paths are not allowed."
        }
        return $true
    })]
[System.Tuple[System.IO.FileInfo,String]]$SomePath
```

However, when you provide an argument like `-SomePath book1.csv,'Some Column Header'` you get:

```
Invoke-MyCmdlet.ps1: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SomePath'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Tuple`2[System.IO.FileInfo,System.String]".
```

Microsoft provides [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#type-conversion-of-parameter-values) on this subject, but if I'm honest I'm struggling to wrap my head around what is going on in that example. There's a lot of syntax and commands there that I'm not familiar with and don't understand their relevance to the type conversion process.

My question is: is there a way to tell PowerShell how to perform the type conversion correctly? If so, what is the syntax for that? Is it documented more clearly elsewhere and I've missed it?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Any reason for not using two separate parameters? Or perhaps accepting a dictionary (path or fileinfo as key, header name as value) as an argument instead?

Comment: Just create your tuple when passing the parameter value: `-SomePath [system.tuple]::Create([io.fileinfo]'book.csv','some column header')`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen convenience for the user and for me. Those parameters will always be tied together. I could separate them, but then I still have the complexity of ensuring if they provide one argument that they also provide the other. I'm certainly open to changing the code, but I'm actually still curious how to do this.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Not an option unfortunately - I'm writing this for someone I am to assume has very little technical skill. Passing types isn't something I want the user to have to do.

Comment: Do you expect to accept multiple such pairs? Or only one?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Multiple - but it will be for different parameters

Comment: I would just make the type an array. Then check for two elements. Then validate each element.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Like I said to MathiasR.Jessen I am certainly open to changing my code. I already actually wrote a workaround and it's basically what you're suggesting. PS interprets it natively as an array of PSObject anyway so it was pretty easy. That said, I actually still want to know how to do this - if nothing else coming from other languages I'm a fan of strong typing and this would be a handy trick to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement and register your own [`PSTypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pstypeconverter) (here using PowerShell classes):

```
class CustomTupleConverter : System.Management.Automation.PSTypeConverter
{
  [bool]
  CanConvertFrom([object]$value, [type]$targetType)
  {
    # We only convert TO [Tuple[FileInfo,string]] 
    if($targetType -ne [System.Tuple[System.IO.FileInfo,string]]){
      return $false
    }

    # ... and only from 2-item arrays consisting of @([string],[string]) or @([FileInfo],[string])
    if($value -is [array] -and $value.Length -eq 2){
      if(($value[0] -is [string] -or $value[0] -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) -and $value[1] -is [string]){
        return $true
      }
    }

    return $false
  }

  [object]
  ConvertFrom([object]$value, [type]$targetType, [IFormatProvider]$format, [bool]$ignoreCase)
  {

    # Resolve individual values in the input array
    $fileInfo = if($value[0] -is [System.IO.FileInfo]){
      $value[0]
    }
    else{
      Get-Item -Path $value[0]
    }

    if($fileInfo -isnot [System.IO.FileInfo]){
      throw "Path didn't resolve to a file."
    }
    $headerName = $value[1] -as [string]

    # Create corresponding tuple and return
    return [System.Tuple]::Create($fileInfo, $headerName)
  }

  [bool]
  CanConvertTo([object]$value, [type]$targetType){
    return $this.CanConvertFrom($value, $targetType)
  }

  [object]
  ConvertTo([object]$value, [type]$targetType, [IFormatProvider]$format, [bool]$ignoreCase){
    return $this.ConvertFrom($value, $targetType, $format, $ignoreCase)
  }
}
```

Once defined, we'll need to register it as a possible type converter for `[System.Tuple[System.IO.FileInfo,string]]`:

```
$targetTypeName = [System.Tuple[System.IO.FileInfo,string]].FullName
$typeConverter = [CustomTupleConverter]
Update-TypeData -TypeName $targetTypeName -TypeConverter $typeConverter
```

Now we can bind 2 strings to a tuple:

```
function Test-TupleBinding
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [System.Tuple[System.IO.FileInfo,string]] $PathAndColumnName
  )

  $PathAndColumnName
}
```

Coversion magic in action during parameter binding:

```
PS C:\> Test-TupleBinding -PathAndColumnName windows\system32\notepad.exe,ColumnNameGoesHere

Item1                           Item2              Length
-----                           -----              ------
C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe ColumnNameGoesHere      2
```